# Requesting walk through of apartment

Tags: rental-property

Can I ask request a walk through from apartment legally before I leave property to make sure I am charged fairly? I normally take pics when moving in/out.

Comment: Unless you lie in a jurisdiction where making requests are illegal I don't see why you can't make a request.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, yes you can and should - photographs simply taken by you are incredibly easy to challenge, so you must get written sign off from the landlord or the landlords agent immediately prior to surrendering the tenancy or you risk leaving yourself open to claims you may find difficult to dispute.

So yes, I would insist on a visual inspection, typically with yourself present at the time, and a written confirmation of the properties acceptable condition prior to handing the keys back.  Every landlord or agent I've dealt with in multiple countries has been fine with this.

If they refuse, then I would demand a written waiver of the properties condition, explicitly noting that no end of tenancy inspection has been done in the tenants presence - in the waiver, I would note the general condition of the property, including your photos, but you have to be explicit that the agent has refused to do an inspection in your presence, and you have to have them acknowledge this.

If they refuse to do the latter, I would go get a lawyer and have them walk through the property with you, noting the condition of the property, and have them notarise the photos as the current condition of the property - the landlord or their agent might not accept this, but a court would find it better evidence than just photos on their own.